# What is the easiest/straightforward way to import functionality from one module in python to another within the same project?

Tags: python, import, packaging

I am new to python. I have a project with the structure as described below and I just want to use functions from one module into another across the package1 and package2 directories. Can I use functions from module3.py in module1.py just by using the import statement (similar as in java or C#)

```
# in package1.module1.py
from package2 import module3.py
```

without any package installation (e.g. locally with 'pip install -e .') and setup.py configuration?

Here an example project structure

```
└── project
    ├── package1
    │   ├── module1.py  <- I want that this module uses functions from module3.py 
    │   └── module2.py
    └── package2
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── module3.py
        ├── module4.py
        └── subpackage1
            └── module5.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should work, and you don't need an `__init__.py` unless you want to import the package itself, i.e.

```
import package2
```

The key thing though, is that 'project' needs to be in your PYTHONPATH. You will not notice that if you run python interactively, because I believe it automatically adds the current directory to the PYTHONPATH.

in practice you'd do

```
from package2 import module3   # notice, no .py
module3.somefn()
```

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` is almost never good practice because it will not scale beyond a couple packages before it becomes impractical to manage.  It is always better to build real packages that may be installed into any Python environment.

Comment: Could be, but the OP asked for a solution that does not require packages.